# ESP32 + rosserial_python over WiFi: Lost sync with device

Tags: ros, wifi, ros-kinetic, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to establish rosserial communication between ESP32 (using ESP-IDF and not Arduino framework) and host Ubuntu machine. Here is my implementation: https://github.com/sachin0x18/rosserial_esp32

I am using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04. rosserial_python version is 0.7.7 (as per package.xml).

I can establish communication over UART using `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py` and it can recognise publisher and subscriber topics.

When I establish communication over WiFi socket using `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py tcp`, rosserial_python on my Ubuntu machine can establish a connection and recognise the publisher and subscriber topics but after 15 seconds, it spits out `Lost sync with device, restarting...` and the same thing happens in a loop

```
[INFO] [1565188371.809821]: ROS Serial Python Node
Fork_server is:  False
[INFO] [1565188371.814939]: Waiting for socket connections on port 11411
waiting for socket connection
[INFO] [1565188380.808154]: Established a socket connection from 10.0.0.137 on port 49464
[INFO] [1565188380.809062]: calling startSerialClient
[INFO] [1565188382.986998]: Note: publish buffer size is 1024 bytes
[INFO] [1565188382.989866]: Setup publisher on chatter [std_msgs/String]
[ERROR] [1565188397.960632]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
[INFO] [1565188398.027021]: Setup publisher on chatter [std_msgs/String]
[ERROR] [1565188413.012285]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
[INFO] [1565188413.073520]: Setup publisher on chatter [std_msgs/String]
```

I am calling `nh.spinOnce()` every 1 second so it shouldn't be a problem of time sync failure.
https://github.com/sachin0x18/rosserial_esp32/blob/master/src/examples/chatter/main/main.c

For debug purpose, I have dumped the bytes that I receive and bytes that I transmit

```
I (3645) event: sta ip: 10.0.0.137, mask: 255.255.254.0, gw: 10.0.0.1                                          
I (3645) wifi station: got ip:10.0.0.137
I (3645) wifi station: Connected to AP
I (3735) wifi station: Successfully connected
Received at read: 0xff
Received at read: 0xfe
Received at read: 0x0
Received at read: 0x0
Received at read: 0xff
Received at read: 0x0
Received at read: 0x0
Received at read: 0xff
I (5955) rosserial: Sending message over ROS 16
I (5965) Sent buffer: ff fe 08 00 f7 0a 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f5     |................|
I (5965) rosserial: Sending message over ROS 80
I (5975) Sent buffer: ff fe 48 00 b7 00 00 7d  00 07 00 00 00 63 68 61     |..H....}.....cha|
I (5985) Sent buffer: 74 74 65 72 0f 00 00 00  73 74 64 5f 6d 73 67 73     |tter....std_msgs|
I (5995) Sent buffer: 2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67 20  00 00 00 39 39 32 63 65     |/String ...992ce|
I (6005) Sent buffer: 38 61 31 36 38 37 63 65  63 38 63 38 62 64 38 38    |8a1687cec8c8bd88|
I (6015) Sent buffer: 33 65 63 37 33 63 61 34  31 64 31 00 04 00 00 21     |3ec73ca41d1....!|
I (7025) rosserial: Sending message over ROS 24
I (7025) Sent buffer: ff fe 10 00 ef 7d 00 0c  00 00 00 68 65 6c 6c 6f       |.....}.....hello|
I (7025) Sent buffer: 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21 f9                                | world!.|
Received at read: 0xff
Received at read: 0xfe
Received at read: 0x8
Received at read: 0x0
Received at read: 0xf7
Received at read: 0xa
Received at read: 0x0
Received at read: 0x6e
Received at read: 0xe6
Received at read: 0x4a
Received at read: 0x5d
Received at read: 0x98
Received at read: 0x1
Received at read: 0x9b
Received at read: 0x7
Received at read: 0xbf
```

I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out with this.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330182/esp32-+-rosserial_python-over-wifi:-lost-sync-with-device/) by [sachin0x18](https://answers.ros.org/users/44580/sachin0x18/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the ROS message "Lost sync with device, restarting..." because of socket read in blocked mode
take a look https://github.com/getsense1/rosserial_esp32
in file esp-idf/components/rosserial_esp32/ros_lib/tcp_client.c
function  unsigned char _conn_ros(void) has call fcntl(sock,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
it's set the socket async mode and look at file esp-idf/components/rosserial_esp32/ros_lib/ESP32Hardware.h
that has functions:
int read()
void write(uint8_t* data, int len)
used async mode

try it

---

Originally posted by [getsense](https://answers.ros.org/users/50090/getsense/) with karma: 26 on 2019-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sachin0x18](https://answers.ros.org/users/44580/sachin0x18/) on 2019-12-25**:
Setting the socket to async mode worked! Thanks !

Since it is non-blocking, it returns with errno 11: EAGAIN continuously (which I ignore) but it works.
Was wondering if rosserial actually requires async read calls or is this just a hacky way to get it working ?
Can it be made blocking with SO_RCVTIMEO ?

**Comment by [getsense](https://answers.ros.org/users/50090/getsense/) on 2019-12-25**:
i think roserial requires async read!
Look at ros/node_handle.h(rosserial lib),  the function spinOnce() ... hardware_.read() and then
the ROS node on PC waiting and rosserial lib on device waiting,  we have lost time sync's